# How to Verify Integer list values in between one particular range

Tags: java, arraylist, selenium-webdriver

```
ArrayList<Integer> hLProductList = getPointsValue(
                    Utility.convertToTextList(mProductListingPage.getProductPoints()));
            logReport("hLProductList : ===== " + hLProductList);

List is displaying as hLProductList : ===== [2490, 990, 6870, 1870, 3740, 1240, 7370, 4370, 2870, 3740, 7370, 990, 2240, 3740, 7120, 3110, 1870, 2120, 3120, 8740, 930, 1870, 4370, 1240, 5620, 2620, 6240, 4620, 4990, 1870, 4120, 1240, 7120, 2120, 1870, 6990, 1620, 3110, 1610, 3240, 3870, 3120, 1870, 370, 2490, 3740, 1490, 3120]
```

How to verify this list of value in between 1 and 10000 range.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check that each element of the list is between the limits, and you are using Java8, you can do the following (stream-approach):

```
if(hlProductList.stream().allMatch(x -> x>=1 && x<=10000)){
    //all in the range
}
else{
    //otherwise
}
```

If you don't use Java8, run over the list in a loop and check each element:

```
boolean oneOutOfRange = false;
for (Integer i : hlProductList){
    if (i>10000||i<1){
        oneOutOfRange=true;
        break;
    }
   }
if (oneOutOfRange){
}
```

Comment: Why not just `hlProductList.stream().allMatch(x -> x>=1 && x<=10000)`?

Comment: I am not using java8

Comment: @ThomasBöhm: I think that should be in && condition. Am I correct?

Comment: @RyanJones , no, because we want to find Elements that are not in the range, either bigger than 10000 OR smaller than 1. If you think about it, there arn't any Elements that are bigger than 10000 AND at the same time smaller than 1 (mathematically impossible)

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the convertToTextList method with a param Range and output object Result like this:

```
public Range{ 
  int start;
  int end;
}
//...
public Result{
  int[] listResult;
  boolean outRange;
}
```

I imagine that in the method convertToTextList there is a cycle, you can compare che occurency of cycle with the Range parameter if it's not null.

so you have now 2 methods:

```
Result convertToTextList(List list, Range range){
  //...do new cycle with compare if range not null
}

//old method rewriting... optimezed
int[] convertToTextList(List list){
  return convertToTextList(list, null).listResult;
}
```